# String to Hex Conversion Using Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net-2010

Im trying to Convert Hexadecimal value to String but i dont know how to do. 
This what i tried to do but it's Int to Hex.

```
    sHex = Hex(Text)
    TextBox2.Text = sHex
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
Function StringToHex(ByVal text As String) As String
    Dim hex As String
    For i As Integer = 0 To text.Length - 1
        hex &= Asc(text.Substring(i, 1)).ToString("x").ToUpper
    Next
    Return hex
End Function
```

use it with the console.

```
Debug.WriteLine(StringToHex("sim0n"))
```

let me know if it works for u.

Comment: No problem at-all glad to help.